# An integral and $\pi(n)$

Tags: integration, polynomials, prime-numbers

Are there polynomials $P,Q\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ satisfying :
$$\int_{0}^{\log n}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{n}{\pi(n)}\quad \text{ for infinitely many }n\in \mathbb{N}$$
Here $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function. I have no idea about this problem. This is a problem from a local magazine, which has stopped publishing so I don't have any answer to this. Thanks.

Comment: Is this definitely an equality you want? I might be overthinking it but if you use Chebyshev's inequalities on the RHS you find the integral is bounded above and below by C ln(x) and D ln(x). This might tell you something about what the integral would look like.

Comment: Well it was given so in the magazine. I think there are no such polynomials. But again guessing isn't gonna do it. And @fretty thanks for commenting, so the rational function $P/Q$ should be linear right?

Comment: I think the equality is the issue here (I feel there should be an easy solution though). I can get approximation easily. By the PNT n/pi(n) is approx of the order ln(n) so you would expect this integral to be of that order (which can easily be made to happen).

Comment: Nice problem :) .. which magazine is it from ? :D

Comment: the magazine is local, so I don't think you will know the name. And also it has stopped publishing. Its name is spectrum.
EDIT : awesome solution. I am speechless!!

Comment: @shadow10 I didn't know Spectrum stopped publishing ! Thanks :-) .. I'm *local* too you know =P

Comment: I think it has!! It is a magazine published by a group of teachers who were interested in teaching Olympiad math, and it was local as in confined in our state lol. Anyways it was nice to meet you :) :) :D EDIT: looks like there is another magazine by that name, so those teachers could have been sued :P

Comment: @shadow10 we can continue this discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) if you like :-) .. (by *local* I meant I am from the same state as that magazine :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say, $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\log n_k}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{n_k}{\pi(n_k)}\quad \text{ for the subsequence } \,\{n_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{N}$.

Then the subsequence $\{n_k\}$ has either infinitely many primes or infinitely many composites.

Either way we have a sequence $\{n_{k_{r}}\}$ of $\{n_k\}$, such that $\pi(n_{k_{r}}+1) = \pi(n_{k_{r}})$.

Let, $\displaystyle F(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}\int_0^{\log x}\dfrac{P(t)}{Q(t)}\,dt$

Then, by Rolle's Mean Value Theorem $\exists\,c_r \in (n_{k_{r}},n_{k_{r}}+1)$, such that $F'(c_r) = 0$, for all $r \in \mathbb{N}$, where $c_r$
 is an unbounded sequence.

Since, $xF'(x) + F(x) = \dfrac{P(\log x)}{xQ(\log x)}$,

Thus, write $R(x) = \dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, we have: $\displaystyle R(\log c_r) = \int_0^{\log c_r} R(t)\,dt$, which we certainly can't have for an unbounded sequence $\{c_r\}$.

Making $x \mapsto e^x$, we see that $T(x) = R(x) - \displaystyle \int_0^x R(x)\,dx$ has infinitely many roots, i.e., $\log {c_r}$ $\implies $ by rolle's theorem once again $R'(c'_r) - R(c'_r) = 0 $, for an unbounded sequence $c'_r \in (c_r,c_{r+1})$, for each $r \in \mathbb{N}$. Contradiction.

Comment: You can't say $\pi(n_{k_r}+1) = \pi(n_{k_r})$ for all $r$, it could be that all $n_k$ are of the form $p-1$. But that doesn't matter, it works equally well if $\pi(n_{k_r}-1) = \pi(n_{k_r})$ for some (or all) $r$. Then you have a typo, $xF'(x)+F(x) = \frac{P(\log x)}{xQ(\log x)}$. Since $\frac{n}{\pi(n)}\sim \log n$, a necessary condition for the equality to hold for infinitely many $n$ is that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} R(x) = 1$, but then $\int_0^{\log c_r} R(x)\,dx \sim \log c_r$, which means the set of solutions of $R(\log c_r)=\int_0^{\log c_r} R(x)\,dx$ is bounded.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot !! :D

Comment: Hey, are you here? :-)))